# Explain the theory behind this problem(if possible using number line or graph or any other method of pictorial representation)

Tags: estimation, si-units, order-of-magnitude

In a situation in which data are known to three significant digits, we write 6.379 m = 6.38 m and 6.374 = 6.37 m. When a number ends in 5, we arbitrarily choose to write 6.375 m = 6.38 m. We could equally well write 6.375 = 6.37 m, “rounding down” instead of “rounding up,” because we would change the number 6.375 by equal increments in both cases. Now consider an order of-magnitude estimate, in which factors of change rather than increments are important. We write $500 m$ ~ $10^{3}$ m because 500 differs from 100 by a factor of 5 while it differs from 1 000 by only a factor of 2. We write 437 m ~ $10^{3}$ m and 305 m ~ $10^{2}$ m. What distance differs from 100 m and from 1000 m by equal factors so that we could equally well choose to represent its order of magnitude as , $10^{2}$ m or as , $10^{3}$ m?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a value $x$ such that

$\displaystyle \frac x {100} = \frac{1000} x
\\ \Rightarrow x^2 = 10^5
\\ \Rightarrow x = \sqrt{10^5} = 100\sqrt{10} \approx 316$

Answer (score 0):

When we are using order of magnitude estimates we are typically using logarithmic scales, and when we are dealing with powers of ten we specifically use base ten logarithms. So $\log_{10}(10) = 1$, $\log_{10}(100) = 2$, $\log_{10}(1000) = 3$ and so on. Then the "mid point" of $100$ and $1000$ would be the number given by:

$$ \log_{10}(x) = 2.5 \tag{1} $$

That is any logarithm less than $2.5$ is rounded down to $2$ and any logarithm greater than $2.5$ is rounded up to $3$. So the number you are looking for is the $x$ in equation (1), and rearranging this gives:

$$ x = 10^{2.5} = 100\sqrt{10} \approx 316.23 $$